# How to access EKS service exposed via ingress by only using AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-api-gateway, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an AWS EKS cluster running and I have an application exposed to outside via ingress with many endpoints.I would like to integrate an AWS API Gateway to access my service from outside instead of the ingress host url which is defined in the manifest file(Kubernetes yaml file).So only access to my application will be from AWS API Gateway.How can I achieve this ?

`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: namespace
  name: example-service-api
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "XX.XX.XX.XX/32"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /path/read
            backend:
              serviceName: example-service-api-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /path/create
            backend:
              serviceName: example-service-api-service
              servicePort: 80
```

I tried to configure regional AWS API Gateway and selected integration type as http and entered the ingress host url which is defined in the yaml file of the Kubernetes.In this step I could reach my application from the AWS API Gateway and also from the ingress host url. But I would like to deny access from ingress host url.So tried the annotation whitelist source range to allow only access from the API Gateway but this resulted in an error "503 service temporarily unavailable" for both the AWS API Gateway and Ingress host url. I think it is because the AWS API Gateway is proxying the ingress host url and that url is getting blocked.Even if doesn't get blocked the ip address of AWS API Gateway keeps changing so it's not a solid solution.Can someone please guide me, I'm not very good with AWS or Kubernetes ?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite complicated architecture and first question to ask is what is the benefit for you from using `AWS API Gateway` instead of standard `ingress`?

If it is really needed I would go with creation of `Internal NLB` for you `k8s`. Then you can create `VPC link` between `API Gateway` and `NLB` ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html)). From there you can setup `API Gateway` with all needed paths and replace `DNS` entry from legacy `LB` to `API Gateway`.

With this setup you will have single domain and you will block any traffic outside of `API Gateway`.